# R - convert <.out> into <.csv> format

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I need to convert model output files into `.csv` format. The original files are in `.out` format, and are tables of data delimited by several spaces in between:

e.g. The original files have about 14,000 rows, but the structure is the same.
Please, use this link for an example file:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1w0f9cq2w6gcbjo/AACoGu6L3yKBGBKODY87lygsa?dl=0

```
time   dayofyr   nit_N2O-N  dnit_N2O-N   dnit_N2-N        NO-N  CUM-N2O(gN/ha)  CUM-NO(gN/ha)
1980.00     1      0.3310        0.3403        0.2022        0.0000        0.6713        0.0000  
1980.00     2      0.3295        0.3400        0.2020        0.0000        1.3408        0.0000  
1980.00     3      0.3280        0.3397        0.2018        0.0000        2.0086        0.0000  
1980.00     4      0.3265        0.3395        0.2016        0.0000        2.6746        0.0000  
1980.00     5      0.3251        0.3393        0.2015        0.0000        3.3389        0.0000  
1980.00     6      0.3237        0.3391        0.2014        0.0000        4.0017        0.0000  
1980.00     7      0.3223        0.3389        0.2013        0.0000        4.6629        0.0000  
1980.00     8      0.3209        0.3387        0.2011        0.0000        5.3225        0.0000  
1980.00     9      0.3195        0.3386        0.2010        0.0000        5.9805        0.0000  
1980.00    10      0.3198        0.4589        0.2868        0.0000        6.7592        0.0000
```

I have tried changing extension to .csv and converting consecutive spaces into ",", but I am afraid there's something I am missing, either in the regex syntax or in the overall rationale.

This is what I've got this far:

```
# change extension of all .out files:
outFiles <- dir(cntPath, "^.+\\.out", full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)
for (nOut in outFiles){
  newOut <- gsub('.out', '.csv', outFiles) # rename files to avoid accidental re-processing
  file.rename(outFiles, newOut)
}
# for each file, eliminate initial spaces, and replace consecutive spaces with a comma, for all rows and columns.
t1 <- read.csv(paste(cntPath, "test2.csv", sep = "/"), header = TRUE, sep = "\t", blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
for (i in 1:length(nrow(t1))) {
  sub("^\\s+", "^\\S", i)
  sub("\\s+", ",", i)
}
```

It should be relatively easy, but I am at lost of where I went wrong.
Any help/suggestions would be appretiated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, backup all your `.out` files somewhere, so that you can recover them when something goes wrong.

After backing up files, do the following in `R`.

The following block of code will find `.out` files in the directory specified in `fp`, read them, write them as `.csv` and finally deletes all `.out` files. If you do not want to delete files, comment the last line with `unlink`.

**EDIT:** used `tryCatch` block to find read|write failing files

```
fp <- "."  # specify file path
fl <- list.files( path = fp, pattern = "*.out", full.names = TRUE ) # get .out files
for (file in fl ){  # loop through files, read it and write it as .csv files. Then delete .out files
flag <- tryCatch( {
    write.table( x = read.table(file = file, header = TRUE ), 
                 file = file.path( fp, gsub( "out$", "csv", basename( file ) ) ), 
                 sep = ",", 
                 row.names = FALSE )
    TRUE
    },
    error = function( x ) { 
      print( paste0( "Problem reading and writing file : ", file ) )
      return(FALSE) } )

if( flag ) unlink( file )  # deletes .out files
}
```

Comment: It works!! thanks Sathish! So the key is rewriting the files as .csv specifying "comma delimited" rather than trying to read them directly in csv and changing the format within the file. I should have thought of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.out` file appears to be a fixed-width format, with the slight problem that the names don't align.

No problem, just skip that row

```r
library(readr)

fwf_txt <- "time   dayofyr   nit_N2O-N  dnit_N2O-N   dnit_N2-N        NO-N  CUM-N2O(gN/ha)  CUM-NO(gN/ha)
1980.00     1      0.3310        0.3403        0.2022        0.0000        0.6713        0.0000  
1980.00     2      0.3295        0.3400        0.2020        0.0000        1.3408        0.0000  
1980.00     3      0.3280        0.3397        0.2018        0.0000        2.0086        0.0000  
1980.00     4      0.3265        0.3395        0.2016        0.0000        2.6746        0.0000  
1980.00     5      0.3251        0.3393        0.2015        0.0000        3.3389        0.0000  
1980.00     6      0.3237        0.3391        0.2014        0.0000        4.0017        0.0000  
1980.00     7      0.3223        0.3389        0.2013        0.0000        4.6629        0.0000  
1980.00     8      0.3209        0.3387        0.2011        0.0000        5.3225        0.0000  
1980.00     9      0.3195        0.3386        0.2010        0.0000        5.9805        0.0000  
1980.00    10      0.3198        0.4589        0.2868        0.0000        6.7592        0.0000  "

write_csv(read_fwf(fwf_txt, fwf_empty(fwf_txt, skip = 1),
                   skip = 1),
          path = "fwf.csv",
          col_names = FALSE)
```

Created on 2018-03-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I didn't know of the `read.fwf` function. I was going nuts trying to figure out a way to read the fixed width format! Nice and simple! Thanks @Hugh!